# Python error importing between modules in the same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, python-module

I'm working on a new project and ran into a problem that I can't find a good explanation for.

TLDR: If I import a function one module into another module in the same directory it runs fine, but won't run if I import that module into a script in a parent directory.

The project is different, but the folder structure below illustrates the problem.

```
main_directory
  |- main_script.py
  utilities
    |- __init__.py
    |- helper_functions.py
    |- my_classes.py
```

###### helper_functions.py

```
def say_hello(name):
  print(f"Hello, my name is {name}!")
```

###### my_classes.py

```
from utilities.helper_functions import say_hello

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def introduce(self):
        say_hello(self.name)
```

###### main_script.py

```
from utilities.helper_functions import say_hello
from utilities.my_classes import MyClass

say_hello('Joe')

Frank = MyClass('Frank')
Frank.introduce()
```

If I run **main_script.py** this works fine:

```
>>Hello, my name is Joe!
>>Hello, my name is Frank!
```

But if I try to run **my_classes.py** I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'`

If I change the import statement within **my_classes.py** to `from helper_functions import say_hello` Then **my_classes.py** runs fine, but **main_script.py** fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper_functions'`.

Is it possible to craft the import statements so that **both** scripts run or is it only possible for a script to be imported or run direct? I gather that the `Path` is different between these two scripts, which explains the behavior, but I don't understand if I'm a) structuring my project the wrong way, b) structuring my imports the wrong way, or c) doing something else totally wrong.

Grateful for any explanations!

*edit for clarity

Comment: I assume the folder called `utilities` in your tree view is actually called `modules`?

Comment: no its not thats why he gets the error ??

Comment: I don't see from your directory structure where `modules` comes from. Scripts are not modules and are not in packages. If you run a script, the packages  / modules it can import are in the directories listed in `sys.path` (note: mostly, there are other ways to find and import modules). When you run a script, python adds the script's directory to sys.path, so you can import things in the same directory of the script. You can always `import sys`, then `print(sys.path)` to see what's going on with any given  script or module.

Comment: Yes what I referred to as `modules` is actually `utilities`, I corrected the original post.  Thanks @tdelaney that's my understanding as well. So does that mean that the answer is that a file cannot be (or should not be structured as) both a script and a package?

Comment: @Zac - Not quite. Normally one should put scripts in a separate directory outside of the package structure. when you write a setup.py to make the whole thing installable, Scripts can go somewhere on the system's executable PATH while modules and packages will go into python's directories. But you can execute modules via, say, `python3 -m mypackage.somescript`. And some installers (like windows) may even make executable wrappers for them during install. You'll have to read up on https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html for that.